# Links with javascript in href are not highlighted by :visited selector in ie 11 after page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have some problem in IE 11 with such links:

```
<a href="javascript:loadUrl('125213523512342412')">link</a>
```

In previous IE versions after opening link and page refreshing the link marked as visited (by color), but in IE 11 links became not marked as visited after each refresh.

I guess that something changed in IE 11, because this worked previously.
Maybe anybody know what was changed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What was changed in IE 11, that now it is not working?

Comment: Without seeing what loadUrl does, hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

Internet Explorer 11 now behaves correctly. For a link to be `:visited` its URL must be present in the browser's history. Because the `javascript:` protocol is telling the browser to perform an action, rather than to (directly) load a URL, it doesn't get entered into the browser's history.

Comment: Yea I understand that but are there any mentions about this in the changes of IE 11 or in the developer guide?